# Getting "Invalid Typeref token" error at random times

Tags: .net, dll, c#-2.0

I have a .Net web application that has been in operation for about 2 years.  We are monitoring it with NewRelic and at least once per day, or sometimes several times per day, we get periods of time where every request results in the following error:

System.BadImageFormatException ... Invalid Typeref token.

If we recycle the App Pool, the error goes away.  If we do nothing, the error goes away on it's own, and everything is fine.

I can't find a pattern of when it happens or which page causes it.

Since recycling the App Pool seems to help, it leads me to believe it's a memory error, so I've been trying to reduce my use of ViewState, particularly on large GridViews.  So far, it has not helped.

Other suggestions for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

firstly I would suggest you to have Log Management. The simplest would be to use a plain text file in which you write error when exception is generated so that you can have a view that no errors are being generated at all.

Secondly you can try with enabling tracing at application level (in Web.config) since you don't know at which page you are getting the exception.

and here is another link that has the same problem and let us know if the following link is not relevant.
[System.BadImageFormatException: How to fix .NET version mismatch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826038/system-badimageformatexception-how-to-fix-net-version-mismatch)